# How to join one busy stream with multiple very small streams in a flink streaming job

Tags: apache-flink

If I have one stream called events.

Events has a ref to system and type.

Then I have a stream called system and a stream called eventType.

In my final result I need data from all three.

In my usecase its required. That if a system or eventType is updated I have to reprocess all events so the end result gets updated.

Now my event stream has gazilions of events and my system and eventType has very few. Lets say 100 in each.

Is there a way to join theese in flink where I can iterate the event stream only once and in the function where I join I want to join with both the other streams.

I looked into broadcasting the small streams but if I do that then the process element context is readOnly (BroadcastProcessFunction) so I cant add the events to the state, and this way reprocess them if I get an update to the system or eventType stream.

The alternative for me is to First iterate the event stream by connecting the event stream with system stream and use a RichCoFlatMapFunction.
And then iterate the resulting stream and use the same functionality but join with the eventType stream now.

What I dont like here is that I will build state with the events in both processes.

I hope there is a smarter way of doing this.

Comment: You said "if a system or eventType is updated I have to reprocess all events so the end result gets updated". I think this means you have to buffer (save in state) all events forever, which isn't scalable or practical. Or am I misunderstanding something in your use case.

Comment: Hi Kkrugler. No you are right. I read in the documentation that its not recommended and could cause problems. But after seing this video from Shopify I decided to try it out. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiGxEGPyqCg the video is not about broadcasting but just about keeping messages in state forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you've interpreted the restrictions on the read-only context in an overly restrictive way. The way it works is this:

- When processing an incoming broadcast message, you can read and write the broadcast state, and iterate over and read and write the key-partitioned state for all keys. This will allow you to re-emit any results that should be updated because of an update to the system or eventType.
- When processing an incoming key-partitioned message, you can read and write the key-partitioned state for that specific key, and read  (but not write) the broadcast state. This will allow you to emit the result for the incoming event, and save that event for later re-processing, as needed.

This should meet your needs for implementing a broadcast join.

Comment: That sounds really good :-) But then I'm not sure I understand what is ment by readonly then?

Comment: The restriction is that you cannot write the broadcast state from the `processElement` method. The broadcast state can only be modified from `processBroadcastElement`.

Comment: thx. Make sence then :-)